# No PushNotification received using FCM in swift 4

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, swift4, ios13

I have followed the steps given in https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client.

There are no errors while running the app but I am unable to receive the push notifications.

1. GoogleService-Info.plist has been added.
2. Enabled push notification services apple account as well as in the  Xcode under capabilities.
3. Build the app in an external device rather than the simulator.

Is there any piece of code or step that I have missed out? Can someone help me sort this out?

Comment: GoogleService-Info.plist -> REVERSED_CLIENT_ID copy that and paste in URL Scheme ? Have you do this ?

Comment: yes, I did @YogeshPatel

Comment: Have you skip the fifth step of firebase project configuration ?

Comment: no, I didn't skip @YogeshPatel